# query laravel not working if pass variable in Where NOT IN

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter items from a database table
what I do is get the ids that I want to exclude and then through -> whereNotIn in laravel, I pass the ids

```
$idcontracts=array();
$idbike=array();
$biciCorretta = array();

$findcontract=Contract::whereRaw('? between data_inizio and data_fine', [$datainizio])->whereRaw('? between data_inizio and data_fine', [$datafine])->get();
        foreach ($findcontract as $key) {
            if (!in_array($key->id,$idcontracts)) {
                array_push($idcontracts,$key->id);
            }
        }
        
        foreach ($idcontracts as $idcontract) {
            $bike_contracts=DB::table('bike_contract')->where('contract_id',$idcontract)->get();
            foreach ($bike_contracts as $bike_contract) {
                if (!in_array($bike_contract->bike_id,$idbike)) {
                    array_push($idbike,$bike_contract->bike_id);
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        $notid=implode("', '",$idbike);
```

up to this point I have no problem.
the result of "implode" gives me the ids I want to remove

this is the result of $idbike and $notid:

[image]

this is the query I write to exclude the ids found:

```
$bikes = Bike::with('category')->whereNotIn('id', [$notid])->orderBy('category_id')->get();
```

the problem is that it doesn't exclude me the ids passed with $notid

but if I manually pass the ids, it removes them instead:

```
$bikes = Bike::with('category')->whereNotIn('id', [40,41,34,36,39])->orderBy('category_id')->get();
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try ->whereNotIn('id', $idbike) .here implode is not neccessary since  wherenotin expect array

Comment: my very trivial mistake, just read the laravel whereNotIn documentation, thanks a lot for the help now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't implode `$notid`, that makes it a `string` and `Laravels` `whereNotIn()` already does that for you.

```
->whereNotIn('id', $idbike)
```

And remove the `$notid` parameter, as it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

implode will return in string, and because of that it will not work correctly, you should pass it as array instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you print data

```
$idbike =[40,41,34,36,39];

print_r($idbike);
```

Output will be Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40
    [1] => 41
    [2] => 34
    [3] => 36
    [4] => 39
)
```

and if you print below code

```
$notid=[implode(",",$idbike)];
print_r($notid);
```

The output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40,41,34,36,39
)
```

So your query become

```
->whereNotIn('id', ["40,41,34,36,39"])
```

so laravel searching for id of  "40,41,34,36,39". so its not returning result

So you can pass array directly to wherenotin

```
->whereNotIn('id', $idbike)
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel, **whereNotIn** method removes elements from the collection that have a specified item value that is contained within the given array. That means  you have to pass an array

So, **idbike** is the array you mentioned

```
$bikes = Bike::with('category')->whereNotIn('id', idbike)->orderBy('category_id')->get();
```